# Bootstrap dropdown is not working with RequireJs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

Here's my code

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout': '/Scripts/vendors/knockout/knockout-2.3.0',
        'knockout-validation': '/Scripts/vendors/knockout/knockout.validation',
        'knockout-postbox': '/Scripts/vendors/knockout/knockout-postbox',
        'knockout-mapping': '/Scripts/vendors/knockout/knockout.mapping',
        'jquery': '/Scripts/vendors/jquery/jquery-1.10.2',
        'bootstrap': '/Scripts/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap'

    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'knockout-validation': ['knockout'],
        'knockout-mapping':  ['knockout'],
        'knockout-postbox': ['knockout']
    },
    enforceDefine : true
});
```

So when I resize my screen I get the responsive dropdown but its not working properly. I hacked in by inserting the scripts directly to the page.That's how I know why the requirejs is not working.

I tried a bunch of questions on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.0

Comment: Okay, it is not working but **how** is it not working?

Comment: So, when the screen is in mobile mode the dropdown is not working. When I clicked it nothing happened, it should have opened the dropdown down.

Comment: Any error messages on the console?

Comment: Not at all. Just the dropdown doesn't side down.

Comment: How is your dropdown created: through the data api or through a JavaScript call? And ok you've configured RequireJS so that it can *find* Bootstrap but what *triggers* Boostrap's loading?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, and the problem in my case is that the bootstrap.js is loaded two times, one by the script tag in the page, and another is loaded by the requirejs.

When the dropdown was clicked, the `toggle` function was fired two times, the first time show the dropdown, and the second time hide the dropdown. So it seems not work.

After remove the script tag from the page, it works.